# Core Data Complex SQL Query

Tags: core-data

I have the following sql query, anyone can assist me converting it to NSPredicate to run through core data?

Can't figure it out...

```
SELECT title, address1, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(36.414376) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(28.155212) ) 
+ sin( radians(36.414376) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
FROM main 
HAVING distance < 0.5 
ORDER BY distance
```

latitude and longitude are doubles in entity main,

many thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.

Core Data and `NSPredicate` do not allow you to perform math.

What you can do, however, is write a `NSPredicate` that returns every address within a box.

What you need to do is pre-calculate the minimum Latitude and Longitude as well as the maximum Latitude and Longitude.

Then your `NSPredicate` turns into:

```
CGFloat minLat = ...;
CGFloat maxLat = ...;
CGFloat minLong = ...;
CGFloat maxLong = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude < %f AND latitude > %f) AND (longitude < %f AND longitude > %f)", minLat, maxLat, minLong, maxLong];
```

From the results of that query you can then narrow down to within a circle to remove the items in the corners. of the box.